# Error 1004 when adding Item value to worksheet and changing row

Tags: excel, vba, collections

Hi I am trying to output my collection to a worksheet in a way that moves to a new row when a # is detected in the text of the current collection item. All of the items will print in one row but I cannot change the row with my current code.

```
For Each Item In jsonValues
       
       e = InStr(1, p(r), "#")
       If e = 1 Then y = y + 1 And currentcolumn = 1
       Worksheets("jsonoutput").Cells(y, currentcolumn).Value = Item
       If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("jsonoutput").Cells(y, currentcolumn).Value <> "" Then currentcolumn = currentcolumn + 1
       r = r + 1
       
Next Item
```

P(r) has the same value as Item - I have tried both in the Instr line but both times I get a 1004 error when e=1 and it is then time to increase y to y+1 It looks like it is setting my y to 0 when I hover over it in the code break? I cannot understand why changing the y is causing an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `And` there is a problem - it doesn't work like that.
Try something like this -

```vb
Dim ws As worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("jsonoutput")

For Each Item In jsonValues
       If Len(Item) > 0 Then

           If InStr(1, Item, "#") = 1 Then 
               y = y + 1
               currentcolumn = 1
           End If
           ws.Cells(y, currentcolumn).Value = Item
           currentcolumn = currentcolumn + 1
       
       end If
       'r = r + 1       
Next Item
```